# Newlines in VB.NET XML literals

Tags: xml, vb.net

Apparently, CR-LF-combinations in VB's XML literals get silently converted to LFs.

Consider the following minimal example:

```vb
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim x As XElement = <xml>1
2</xml>

        ' Print Bytes
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("-", x.Value.Select(Function(c) AscW(c).ToString("X2"))))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Compiled with Visual Studio 2017 (Framework 4.5.2), this yields

```
31-0A-32
```

rather than

```
31-0D-0A-32
```

as I would have expected. I checked the source file with a binary editor and it definitely contains CR-LF (0D-0A) between 1 and 2 in the xml literal.

Is this officially documented behavior or just some implementation detail of my compiler that I cannot rely upon? If the former, where is it documented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft is observing the accepted XML standard, which is to use just a line feed character for line breaks in XML.  That is for interoperability with non-Windows systems, which generally use just line feed.  Windows uses CR-LF as standard but you'll generally find that just LF works as a line break on Windows too.

Comment: `but you'll generally find that just LF works as a line break on Windows too.` - Except for in Notepad. ;)

Comment: If the OP _really_ wants the  cr-lf, the example element can be created: `Dim x as New XElement("xml", "1" & vbCrLf & "2")`.  Certainly is more cumbersome this way, though.

Comment: @MarkL: Currently, I just `.Replace(vbLf, vbCrLf)`, but this will break horribly if VB's treatment of XML literals changes (hence my question here).

Comment: *"...you'll generally find that just LF works as a line break on Windows too"* Depends on the UI library: Some controls will show it, others won't. I happend to use one which doesn't (MS Access TextBox).